# How to disable padding in paypal card payments fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal

I have a problem with paypal card payments fields. As you can see padding is very big in them and i don't now why. I tried to zero the padding in all possible places but it didn't help. Any idea how i can do this?

[image: photo]

Code look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may not be the padding. It may be the height.

Comment: you shouldn't have any access to those fields, paypal's forms are sandboxed. You also shouldn't care about those fields: it's not your content. It's third party content that folks can only trust if you don't change anything about it. Even if you "just remove some padding", no one can trust you.

Comment: I know this is paypal thing not my but if they allow you to edit styles, why not use it, it looks very bad and does not encourage you to buy by it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> TRY THIS!

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Open ***Developer Console*** `(Ctrl+shift+I`) in your chrome browser.

Right click on each field and inspect. See whether that is padding or height and adjust accordingly.

Also, sometimes there is a CSS being applied from some other CSS file. Use `!important` to cross-check whether that is the case.

That's all I can say as of now as per your information provided in the question :)

UPDATE: **Demo of Developer Console:**
[image]

Always do this step, when something seems broken or not as per requirment.

Comment: in dev console there is no padding or any thing like this and !important does not work

Comment: For each element on right side, we can see what is the style being applied. See the styles for your input fields. There only increase decrease height etc. Hope you understood what I am trying to say.

Comment: Have updated the answer for you. Every HTML element has a CSS, and we can easily find that CSS right side of the developer console. And click on any HTML element on left side and find its CSS on the right side. We can play around CSS here also for debugging . Hope you understood now :)

Comment: I know what you mean and in styles there is nothing and it looks like the element is problem not padding or margin

Comment: No dear:) you scroll down on right side. Or there is a computed tab next to styles check the styles from there once

Comment: I updated the question with image of this

Comment: Listen my friend. We have 4 fields there. Right and they have a background-color of white. Right. So that is the CSS applied. Similary there will be width, height. You can find those all within the styles tab on right side of Developer Console... Scroll down a bit not fully to the bottom (That's a box-model only) .I want you to scroll slowly down and and see from what file are they coming. file names are also mentioned there on right corner :)

Comment: That's why I asked the question because I thought that someone also had this problem and found out where the distance is automatically made

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the only way it works is to make an element height 20px, but that still doesn't fix the problem how to adjust this padding without constant value

Comment: There is no padding. You haven't provided the actual rendered CSS for inspection, so we can't tell you how to adjust it.

Comment: height 100% will be based on container height